# Form PHP Undefined variable

Tags: php, html5

Amigos tengo un problema resulta que es un formulario en donde externamente debo capturar los datos y agregarlo en una base datos, la base de datos se conecta perfectamente pero al tomar las variables siempre me manda el mismo mensaje de error. por favor ayúdenme.

```html
<form action="submit_cdd.php" method="POST" class="ins-text formulario">
     <h3>PREINSCRIPCIÓN</h3>
     <label>Nombres y Apellidos <span>*</span></label>
     <input type="text" name="nombres" required>
     <label>Correo electrónico <span>*</span></label>
     <input type="email" name="email" required>
     <label>Dirección</label>
     <input type="text" name="direccion">
     <label>Número de teléfono <span>*</span></label>
     <input type="number" name="telefono" required>
     <label>Tipo de Documento:<span>*</span></label>
     <select required>
        <option value="none">--------Seleccionar-----</option>
        <option value="CC">Cédula de Ciudadanía</option>
        <option value="CE">Cédula Extranjera</option>
        <option value="TI">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
        <option value="NP">Numero de Pasaporte</option>
     </select>
     <label>Número de Documento <span>*</span></label>
     <input type="text" name="document" required>
     <label>Comentarios</label>
     <textarea type="text" name="comentarios"></textarea>
     <submit class="btn btn-yellow" onclick="submit()" href="#" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

y el codigo php.

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST["nombres"]))
        {
          $nombre = $_POST["nombres"];
        } 
        if (isset($_POST["email"]))
        {
          $email = $_POST["email"];
        } 
        if (isset($_POST["direccion"]))
        {
          $direccion = $_POST["direccion"];
        } 
        if (isset($_POST["telefono"]))
        {
          $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
        } 
        if (isset($_POST["document"]))
        {
          $document = $_POST["document"];
        } 
        if (isset($_POST["comentarios"]))
        {
          $comentarios = $_POST["comentarios"];
        } 
        echo $nombre;      
        header("refresh:1 url=curso-derecho-disciplinario.html");
?>
```

Comment: La forma de agradacer al que te ayudó es **aceptando** su respuesta (el símbolo `✓` a la izquierda de la respuesta). Así, **ambos** ganais reputación. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede que el error que te devuelve sea en parte a que no existe la etiqueta HTML `submit`, este es tu código incorrecto:

```
<submit class="btn btn-yellow" onclick="submit()" href="#" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</submit>
```

Puedes sustituirlo por la siguiente línea

```
<input class="btn btn-yellow" type="submit" value="Enviar formulario">
```

Comment: Gracias lazaro, no me habia dado cuenta jeje, por otra parte ¿como hago para que el resultado se muestre en el documento html, sin que me mande al código php? Gracias.

Comment: Por nada. Necesitas a PHP para eso, el es el encargado de procesar la información enviada por el formulario.